# access the properties of an object inside an object class which is also inside an object class

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-services

How do we access the properties of an object inside an object class which is also inside an object class?

Here I can access test.company.phone but not the test.company.company_name.company_id in the ng.html file?

```
 public test: Employee = {
    emp_id: 0,
    name: 'test',
    surname: 'test2',
    company: {
      c_id: 12,
      company_name: [{ company_id: 101, name: 'abc' },{ company_id: 101, name: 'abc' }] 
      phone: '+665589898',
    },
  };
```

Comment: `company_name` is an array, so of course you need to do an array access, e.g. `test.company.company_name[0].company_id`. In the html you could e.g. use `ngFor` on `company_name`.

Answer (score 0):

The test.company.phone property is a string, which means there is only one value ('+665589898') and company.company_name property is an array of objects. So you need to iterate through the array with [NgFor directive](https://angular.io/api/common/NgForOf) or access it by index with string interpolation like the code below:

```
<div>First company name{{ test.company.company_name[0].company_id }}</div>
<div>Second company name{{ test.company.company_name[1].company_id }}</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, what if there were more employee ids as well? eg: 
public test: Employee = [
  {
    emp_id: 0,
    name: 'test',
    surname: 'test2',
    company: {
      c_id: 12,
      company_name: [{ company_id: 101, name: 'abc' },{ company_id: 101, name: 'abc' }] 
      phone: '+665589898',
    }, 
      {
    emp_id: 1,
    name: 'test1',
    surname: 'test3',
    company: {
      c_id: 13,
      company_name: [{ company_id: 101, name: 'abc' },{ company_id: 101, name: 'abc' }] 
      phone: '+66558890',
    },
  ];

Comment: You need an array of Employees like that:
 public test: Employee[] =[ {employee1 object },{ employee 2 object } ] 
Then in the html you can use the NgFor Directive:
<div class="container" *ngFor="let employee of employees">
<p>Employee  first company name{{ employee.company.company_name[0].company_id }}</p>
<p>Employee second company name{{ employee.company.company_name[1].company_id }}</p>
</div>